# useradd: invalid option -- 'n'

Tags: linux, user-accounts, user

I'm trying to create new user with default values, but it gives me error that such option is invalid. So does something changed and I need to use something else to create user with default values?

```
 sudo useradd -n user
```

`useradd: invalid option -- 'n'`

I'm using ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `-n` does not exist as an option (according to my `useradd` manpage).

It is not clear what you mean by default falues but the most straighforward way to create a user and place him into the `users` group would be

```
useradd -g users <username>
```

The user needs to be part of at least one group... which in this case is `users` (initial group).

With options like `-m` you can create a home-directory for that user along the way.

Comment: I solved this with `adduser` command, that helped craeting user interactively. Using `useradd` always created user with some strange options. Like you couldn't even use `cd` and I guess shell default profile was not used so it looked strange. But with `adduser` it creates user with all default options my first linux user gets (except access rights of course)